# Get allocation ID form public (Elastic) IP in CDK

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cdk

Is there a native way to retrieve an allocation ID from a public Elastic IP (or the opposite) in CDK?

Given an already existing IP, I'm currently forced to instanciate a Boto3 client to get the matching allocation ID. Isn't there a better way to load a `CfnEip` and resolve both its `public_ip` and `allocation_id` attributes?

```py
import boto3

c = boto3.client("ec2")
address = c.describe_addresses(PublicIps = ['123.45.67.89'])['Addresses'][0]

instance = ec2.Instance(…)

ec2.CfnEIPAssociation(self, "EipAssociation",
    allocation_id = address["AllocationId"],
    instance_id = instance.instance_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a layer 1 construct for EIPs called [CfnEIP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnEIP.html) which you can use to allocate EIPs.

It has a property called [attr_allocation_id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnEIP.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnEIP.attr_allocation_id%5D) which you can use to access the EIP's allocation ID.

If you need the allocation ID of a preallocated EIP you probably can use an [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html) to let a Lambda function call the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html) for you. I don't know whether it makes a big difference in your case though, unless for example it is important that you get the allocation ID right after the instance got created.

If you want to use the AWSCustomResource you also have to [describeAddresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/OpsWorks.html#describeAddresses-property) and set the `PublicIps` parameter to a list including the IP you are looking for. Note that I didn't try this code myself:

```
    eip = cr.AwsCustomResource(self, f"MyEIP",
        on_create=cr.AwsSdkCall(
            physical_resource_id=cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(instance.instance_name),
            service='EC2',
            action='describeAddresses',
            parameters={
                "PublicIps": ["123.45.67.89"]
            }
        ),
        policy=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(
            resources=cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE,
        ),
    )
    allocation_id = eip.get_response_field("Addresses.0.AllocationId")
```